# How to apply log to an numpy sparse matrix elementwise

Tags: python, numpy

Im working with python, sklearn and numpy and I am creating the following sparse matrix:

```
    feats = tfidf_vect.fit_transform(np.asarray(tweets))
    print(feats)

    feats=np.log(np.asarray(feats))
```

but I am getting the following error when I apply the log:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "src/ef_tfidf.py", line 100, in <module>
   feats=np.log(np.asarray(feats))
   AttributeError: log
```

the error is related with the fact that feats it's a sparse matrix I would appreciate any help with this, I mean a way to apply the log to a sparse matrix.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? If most of the inputs are 0, most of the outputs will be -inf. If the inputs aren't mostly 0, why have a sparse matrix?

Comment: yes I am sure, tanks for the support.

Comment: sorry I agree with you ,instead of this i want to apply the log to all the enters of the matrix that are distinct of zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to convert a sparse matrix to an ndarray is with the `toarray` method:

```
feats = np.log(feats.toarray())
```

`np.array` doesn't understand sparse matrix inputs.

---

If you want to only take the log of non-zero entries and return a sparse matrix of results, the best way would probably be to take the logarithm of the matrix's `data` and build a new sparse matrix with that data.

How that works through the public interface is different for different sparse matrix types; you'd want to look up the constructor for whatever type you have. Alternatively, there's the private `_with_data` method:

```
feats = feats._with_data(np.log(feats.data), copy=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

So I actually needed to take something like `log(p+1)` for some sparse matrix p and I found this scipy method [log1p](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.log1p.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.log1p) which returns exactly that on a sparse matrix. I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'm just putting this here in case it helps anyone.

You could apply this to the original question with

```
feats = (feats-1).log1p()
```

This has the advantage of keeping feats sparse.

Answer (score 0):

`fit_transform()`returns [`scipy.sparse.coo_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html) object, which has `data` attribute linked to data array of the sparse matrix

You can use the `data` attribute to manipulate non-zero data of coo sparse matrix directly, as following:

`feats.data = np.log(feats.data)`